# Acessar valores dentro de um array

Tags: php

Estou com uma duvida para realizar acesso a variável dentro de uma array, sou meio novato no mundo PHP(somente ao lado do servidor sem HTML) e estou precisando tratar uma resposta do servidor.

Não estou conseguindo acesso básico a variável

Se tento

```
echo $data[0]->id
```

retorna

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

O array segunda resposta do print_r

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => hook_98kmOL1sMfnZqoPL
            [url] => https://70cfee17.ngrok.io/notifications/payment
            [account] => Array
                (
                    [id] => acc_jZkdN857et650oNv
                    [name] => Lojinha
                )

            [event] => order.paid
            [status] => failed
            [attempts] => 3/3
            [last_attempt] => 2017-03-24T21:32:07Z
            [created_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:59Z
            [response_status] => 404
            [response_raw] => Tunnel 70cfee17.ngrok.io not found
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => or_e36l73IwgF7MlJwx
                    [code] => ER30H4MU4N
                    [amount] => 199
                    [currency] => BRL
                    [closed] => 1
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => oi_NqW9Rb2LTbsqRa3n
                                    [description] => FLIP Payment
                                    [amount] => 199
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [status] => active
                                    [created_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                    [updated_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                )

                        )

                    [customer] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => cus_le6ZqXjiBSEOWdoA
                            [name] => Matheus Moreira
                            [email] => mmoreira@mundipagg.com
                            [delinquent] => 
                            [created_at] => 2016-11-25T23:45:04Z
                            [updated_at] => 2016-12-26T21:34:45Z
                        )

                    [status] => paid
                    [created_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                    [updated_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:59Z
                    [closed_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:59Z
                    [charge] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => ch_56YNm9akt4i6mKQ8
                            [code] => ER30H4MU4N
                            [gateway_id] => b21c20f8-21e1-4f56-ac1c-34425c9e9dc9
                            [amount] => 199
                            [status] => paid
                            [currency] => BRL
                            [payment_method] => credit_card
                            [due_at] => 2017-03-24T00:00:00Z
                            [paid_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:59Z
                            [created_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                            [updated_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                            [customer] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => cus_le6ZqXjiBSEOWdoA
                                    [name] => Matheus Moreira
                                    [email] => mmoreira@mundipagg.com
                                    [delinquent] => 
                                    [created_at] => 2016-11-25T23:45:04Z
                                    [updated_at] => 2016-12-26T21:34:45Z
                                )

                            [last_transaction] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => tran_MpnYkMXhOBTb7Ze8
                                    [transaction_type] => credit_card
                                    [gateway_id] => 9ac7ee2c-02a1-4b19-9f7e-168739a0427b
                                    [amount] => 199
                                    [status] => captured
                                    [success] => 1
                                    [installments] => 1
                                    [acquirer_name] => simulator
                                    [acquirer_affiliation_code] => MUNDI
                                    [acquirer_tid] => 266699
                                    [acquirer_nsu] => 848780
                                    [acquirer_auth_code] => MUNDI
                                    [acquirer_message] => Simulator|Transação de simulação autorizada com sucesso
                                    [acquirer_return_code] => 0
                                    [operation_type] => auth_and_capture
                                    [credit_card] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => card_yB3ma9rS8HW7mnA9
                                            [last_four_digits] => 8229
                                            [brand] => Amex
                                            [holder_name] => Tony Stark
                                            [exp_month] => 1
                                            [exp_year] => 2018
                                            [status] => active
                                            [created_at] => 2016-11-29T21:14:07Z
                                            [updated_at] => 2016-11-29T21:14:07Z
                                            [billing_address] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [street] => Malibu Point
                                                    [number] => 10880
                                                    [zip_code] => 90265
                                                    [neighborhood] => Central Malibu
                                                    [city] => Malibu
                                                    [state] => CA
                                                    [country] => US
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [created_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                    [updated_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                )

                        )

                    [charges] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => ch_56YNm9akt4i6mKQ8
                                    [code] => ER30H4MU4N
                                    [gateway_id] => b21c20f8-21e1-4f56-ac1c-34425c9e9dc9
                                    [amount] => 199
                                    [status] => paid
                                    [currency] => BRL
                                    [payment_method] => credit_card
                                    [due_at] => 2017-03-24T00:00:00Z
                                    [paid_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:59Z
                                    [created_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                    [updated_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                    [customer] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => cus_le6ZqXjiBSEOWdoA
                                            [name] => Matheus Moreira
                                            [email] => mmoreira@mundipagg.com
                                            [delinquent] => 
                                            [created_at] => 2016-11-25T23:45:04Z
                                            [updated_at] => 2016-12-26T21:34:45Z
                                        )

                                    [last_transaction] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => tran_MpnYkMXhOBTb7Ze8
                                            [transaction_type] => credit_card
                                            [gateway_id] => 9ac7ee2c-02a1-4b19-9f7e-168739a0427b
                                            [amount] => 199
                                            [status] => captured
                                            [success] => 1
                                            [installments] => 1
                                            [acquirer_name] => simulator
                                            [acquirer_affiliation_code] => MUNDI
                                            [acquirer_tid] => 266699
                                            [acquirer_nsu] => 848780
                                            [acquirer_auth_code] => MUNDI
                                            [acquirer_message] => Simulator|Transação de simulação autorizada com sucesso
                                            [acquirer_return_code] => 0
                                            [operation_type] => auth_and_capture
                                            [credit_card] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => card_yB3ma9rS8HW7mnA9
                                                    [first_six_digits] => 342793
                                                    [last_four_digits] => 8229
                                                    [brand] => Amex
                                                    [holder_name] => Tony Stark
                                                    [exp_month] => 1
                                                    [exp_year] => 2018
                                                    [status] => active
                                                    [created_at] => 2016-11-29T21:14:07Z
                                                    [updated_at] => 2016-11-29T21:14:07Z
                                                    [billing_address] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [street] => Malibu Point
                                                            [number] => 10880
                                                            [zip_code] => 90265
                                                            [neighborhood] => Central Malibu
                                                            [city] => Malibu
                                                            [state] => CA
                                                            [country] => US
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [created_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                            [updated_at] => 2017-03-24T21:21:58Z
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para você acessar a variável id você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
echo $data[0]['id'];
```

Esse array é multidimencional, ou seja, para acessar informações mais "internas" do array você pode ir adicionando `['kay']` com suas respectivas chaves.

Você só deve usar `->` para acessar objetos, que não é o caso.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Como o Phelipe disse, você pode acessar o elemento do array utilizando as chaves do elemento:

```
$value = $data[0]['id'];
```

Mas caso queira trata-lo como objeto, você também pode fazer um cast, ficaria assim:

```
$value = ((object)$data[0])->id;
```